# Sending keystrokes to an application that is not in foreground (ie minimized)

Tags: c#, keypress

I have been searching for a working example on how to accomplish this, but no luck so far.

This is what I have right now :

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr
        wParam, IntPtr lParam);

Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process p in processlist)
            {
                if (p.ProcessName == "notepad")
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("bu");
                    /*

                    LRESULT PostMessage( HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

                    WM_KEYDOWN
                           WPARAM wParam
                            LPARAM lParam;
                    Parameters
                        wParam
                            Specifies the virtual-key code of the nonsystem key. 
                        lParam
                            Specifies the repeat count, scan code, extended-key flag, 
                            context code, previous key-state flag, and transition-state flag, 
                            as shown in this table.

                    ......So......

                    LRESULT debugvalue = PostMessage( Handle_to_where_the_message_is_going,
                                                      WM_KEYDOWN, (WPARAM)VK_ENTER, (LPARAM)0)


                     */
                    uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
                    PostMessage(p.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto("something"), IntPtr.Zero);
                }
            }
```

Now, what am I doing wrong?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28VS.85%29.aspx May be of assistance

Comment: "Now, what am I doing wrong?" - For starters, you could mark some answers on your other questions...  That might get you more responses, especially when you're pasting large amounts of code instead of asking a pointed question.

Comment: Why would you want to capture keystrokes in a minimized application?  Unless you can justify what you're trying to do and I'm wrong in assumptions, I'm hoping a moderator gives you a nice vacation.

Comment: @Nick, he wants to send keystrokes to a minimized app, not capture them.

Comment: @Mikael - Same thing, different terminology, my point is...I can think of 1000 ways this is misused, only about 5 it's useful for, and based on the user's previous questions of trying to find what other software the user's running....

Comment: Based on the other questions I have asked you could very well had read that I am trying to automate the start-stop of a webserver application. I would like this to be done even if it was minimized, so not to mess up other already made automation tools made by programmers before me.

I didnt paste massive amount of code, its a one liner, with the backup code so that to avoid meanning less questions and to help other people after me with same problem.

Also went with the trouble of pasting the complete explanation of said Pinvoke method, to further help out.

I apologize for beeing complete.

Comment: @Nick I agree with misuse. And reading is more likely to be misuse than sending keystrokes. I have a case myself these days with a media player app created in Adobe Air which don't support media keys. I'm in the process of mapping a press on a media key and pass it on as say "space" to the media app.

Comment: @Nick, still trying to figure out what you mean by "Same thing, different terminology" as to it beeing used on a keylogger. A keylogger CAPTURES keypresses, does not send them. As far as security goes, there are far easier ways to hack/monitor/steal information from users. You can even read controls from inside other applications using nothing but the Automation library MS has for us. As for the vacation, I am hoping a moderator gives you one too, for trolling and derailing/offtopic, when one cant distinguish a keypresser from a keylogger and even complains about it,nothing useful can come out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of things wrong.  You are sending the message to the Process.Handle instead of the window handle.  Use at least Process.MainWindowHandle.  Also, you should send a virtual keystroke, not a string.  The Keys enumeration gets you the key codes.  Sending a string requires a keystroke for each letter in the string.  Also, you should send the WM_KEYUP message as well.  Also, the receiving application is likely to use the keyboard state to determine whether the Shift, Ctrl or Alt keys are down and translate the keystroke to a typing key accordingly.  You can't fake that with PostMessage().

That ought to get it somewhat working.  To make it truly reliable, I think you need a WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK hook, set by SetWindowsHookEx().  You can't write that in C#, it doesn't support injecting DLLs into another process.  Check out what [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) can do for you.